# gulp command not combining JavaScript files in Laravel framework. Gives strange error

Tags: node.js, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I have the following elixir function in Laravel framework:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir(function(mix) {
   mix.sass('app.scss');
   mix.styles(['bootstrap.min.css','app.css'], null, 'public/css');
   mix.scripts(['bootstrap.min.js','jquery.min.js'], null, 'public/js');
   mix.version('public/css/all.css');
});
```

The null parameters are supposed to automatically create all.css in public/css folder and all.js in public/js folder. While the css file is combined properly I get the following error for javascript files:

```
[12:53:30] 'scripts' errored after 952 ms
[12:53:30] Error: Cannot find module '../internal/assignWith'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/htdocs/t2ci/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/lodash/object/assign.js:1:80)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
[12:53:30] Error in plugin 'run-sequence'
Message:
An error occured in task 'scripts'.
```

I've wasted several hours searching the internet for solutions but I haven't found any yet.  Would anyone have encountered this sort of error?

Comment: Your *node_modules* might be corrupted. Does it work properly after `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hkan.  That worked perfect!

Comment: Glad it worked. Cheers! Also posted as answer, don't forget to accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *node_modules* might be corrupted. Does it work properly after `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`?